# How to include RSS feeds inside a node?

Tags: 8, feeds

I would like to create a node that displays 5 RSS feeds from 5 different external sites. I have the RSS URL of the external sites, and I would like to find a simple way to display the last elements of these feeds inside my node.

I have already looked at the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module, but it creates a node for each element of the given RSS feeds.
How can I display the last elements from different RSS feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use [Aggregator](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/aggregator/configuring-aggregator), you dont have to map into a new content type RSS Feeds like on Feeds module.

Follow this:

1. Active Aggregator core module.
2. Add a new chanel per each feed URL under /admin/config/services/aggregator, defining a name and time for importing by cron.
3. Create a view with a display of type "Aggreator", Here you can make a comun view, ordering by date, limiting by 1 result, and filtering by each channel.

I hope this help.